# Detect block below a player in a vehicle

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm having trouble detecting a block below the player when the player is riding a vehicle.

`execute at @a if block ~ ~ ~ minecraft:rail run tellraw @s "Teste"`

This command works only if the player is by foot.

I've tried adjusting the Y with no success.

Answer (score 1):

If you press `F3 + B` while riding the minecard, you will notice your hitbox going bellow the block. Try detecing "above you" (higher ~Y). The following worked:

`/execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:rail run say @s`

Also, note that doing `@s` with only `at @a` will not work as exepected, make sure to add `as @a` before and use `at @s` instead.